# .apply(pd.to_numeric) returns error message

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with two columns I want to convert to numeric type.  I use the following code:

```
df[["GP","G"]]=df[["GP","G"]].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Python returns the following error message:

```
File "C:\Users\Alexandros_7\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4157, in _apply_standard
results[i] = func(v)

File "C:\Users\Alexandros_7\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\util.py", line 115, in to_numeric
coerce_numeric=coerce_numeric)

File "pandas\src\inference.pyx", line 612, in pandas.lib.maybe_convert_numeric (pandas\lib.c:53558)

File "pandas\src\inference.pyx", line 598, in      pandas.lib.maybe_convert_numeric (pandas\lib.c:53344)

ValueError: ('Unable to parse string', 'occurred at index GP')
```

How can I fix this problem?  How can I convert multiple column types at once with a command?  Thank you!

Comment: Your DataFrame contains some entry that can't be converted to a numeric value, e.g., `df = pd.DataFrame({'GP': ['a'], 'G': ['2']})`.

Answer (score 5):

Your code will only work if all the data can be parsed to numeric.

If not, there is at least one value in dataframe which is not convertible to numeric. You can use `errors` parameter according to your choice in such case. Here is an example.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : list('aabbcd'), 'B' : list('ffghhe')})

>>> df
   A  B
0  a  f
1  a  f
2  b  g
3  b  h
4  c  h
5  d  e

>>> df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
   A  B
0  a  f
1  a  f
2  b  g
3  b  h
4  c  h
5  d  e

>>> df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
    A   B
0 NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN
4 NaN NaN
5 NaN NaN

>>> df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='raise')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4042, in apply
    return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4138, in _apply_standard
    results[i] = func(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4020, in f
    return func(x, *args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/util.py", line 98, in to_numeric
    coerce_numeric=coerce_numeric)
  File "pandas/src/inference.pyx", line 612, in pandas.lib.maybe_convert_numeric (pandas/lib.c:53932)
  File "pandas/src/inference.pyx", line 598, in pandas.lib.maybe_convert_numeric (pandas/lib.c:53719)
ValueError: ('Unable to parse string', u'occurred at index A')
>>>
```

Here is the documentation for `errors`

> errors : {‘ignore’, ‘raise’, ‘coerce’}, default ‘raise’
>
> If ‘raise’, then invalid parsing will raise an exception
>
> If ‘coerce’,then invalid parsing will be set as NaN
>
> If ‘ignore’, then invalid parsing will return the input

Comment: My apologies for the downvote. This lambda is redundant, and its absence is not the cause of the problem.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I haven't understood.

Comment: `lambda x: func(x)` is exactly the same as `func`. In particular, you can pass either to `apply`. Again, sorry for downvoting the answer.

Comment: OK. I still think the `lambda` is redundant here, but it also doesn't do much harm. All the best.